# Laravel/Blade: How to style error message in form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I made a form with validation (laravel with blade template engine) and it works as expected.

Here's the code:

```
@if ($errors->first('email'))
  {{ Form::text('email', null, $attributes = array('class'=>'error')) }}
  {{ $errors->first('email', '<small class=error>:message</small>') }}
@else
  {{ Form::text('email') }}
@endif
```

Is there a cleaner solution?

I'd like to write `Form::text('email')` only once...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be fairly self-explanatory

```
{{ Form::text('email', null, $attributes = $errors->has('email') ? array('class'=>'error') : array()) }}
@if ($errors->has('email'))
    {{ $errors->first('email', '<small class=error>:message</small>') }}
@endif
```

Comment: works perfect, thanks
notice to others: when using a password-field instead of an text-field, you have to delete the second parameter (null)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a macro if you really want to be elegant:

```
Form::macro('textWithErrors', function($name, $value, $attributes, $errors){
    if ($errors->has($name)) {
        if (array_key_exists('class', $attributes)) {
            $attributes['class'] .= ' error';
        } else {
            $attributes['class'] = 'error';
        }
    }
    $output = Form::text($name, $value, $attributes);
    if ($errors->has($name)) {
        $output .= $errors->first($name, '<small class=error>:message</small>');
    }
    return $output;
});
```

Use `Form::textWithErrors()` in place of the `Form::text()` call, and pass in the errors `MessageBag`, which is always defined.

Answer (score 0):

Alfred, you can also do this,  think this is fairly simple

```
{ Form::text('email', null, $attributes = $errors->has('email') ? array('class'=>'error') : array()) }}
<span class="errors">{{ $errors->first('email') }}
```

Your css class can be something like this

```
.errors { color: #F00; }
```

This errors is only executed when the validation rules fail